# Parsing JSON if it contains specific value of the property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I use java spring in my project.

I have this JSON annotation:

```
public class info {

    @JsonProperty("ProjectId")
    public int projectId;
    
    other props...
}
```

Is it possible to parse the only JSON that has ProjectId equal to 50?

Comment: Is accepting `info` as a map of key value pairs instead of an object you mentioned an option?

Comment: You need to parse the json input to know that the projectId is 50, so I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: maybe you can use your jsonString.contains("\"ProjectId\" : 50")!